# AngularJs printing double quotation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using AngularJs in my MVC application, I am kinda new to AngularJs. I am having a problem and couldnt find it out. AngularJs prints double quotation inside html. here is my sample code.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="visible-md visible-lg col-md-3 text-right" ng-controller="WeatherController">
    <div class="weather">
        <i id="weather_icon" class="icon">
            {{condition_image}}
        </i>
        <h3>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
            <span id="cityName"></span>

            <span class="temp">
                <span>
                    {{weathers}}
                </span>
            </span>
        </h3>
        <span class="date" id="current_date">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is how I set the variable.

```
$http.get('/api/getweatherbycityname/' + $city).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.weathers = data.condition_temp + '℃ ';
                $scope.condition_image = '<img src=\'~/Images/Weather/wi-yahoo-' + data.condition_code + '.png\' />';
                //document.getElementById("weather_icon").className += ' wi-yahoo-' + data.condition_code;
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                //alert(data);
            })
```

Comment: code seems fine, I guess the `"` you get are inside the variable `$scope.condition_image` or `$scope.weathers`

Comment: Hi @Naigel, I posted the $scope.condition_image. would you please check

Comment: Can you post your data inside condition_image and weathers?

Comment: I posted it @Rahul

Comment: @ayilmaz it seems good... anyway I was posting an answer like Rhaul's one that is the best way in this case. Try to keep in your scope variables only the minimum amount of information needed, not all the HTML element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

Use ng-src

In HTML:

```
    <img ng-src="{{condition_image}}" />
```

In Angularjs code:

```
 $scope.condition_image = '~/Images/Weather/wi-yahoo-' + test + '.png\';
```

Comment: @ayilmaz would you mind to accept the answer if it helped you ;)